# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.getPropertyDescriptor when using <managed-property><list-entries>

Tags: jsf, managed-property

im trying to get the following bean tow work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">



    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>indexHandler</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>myfirst.MBindex</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
        <managed-property>
            <description>a</description>
            <list-entries>
                <value>Film 1</value>
                <value>Film 2</value>
                <value>Film 3</value>
            </list-entries>
        </managed-property>
    </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

```
    package myfirst;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MBindex {
        private List<String> stfilme = new ArrayList<String>();

        public List<String> getStfilme() {
            return stfilme;
        }

        public void setStfilme(List<String> stfilme) {
            this.stfilme = stfilme;
        }
    }
```

Stacktrace

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Unerwarteter Fehler beim Verarbeiten von verwaltetem Bean indexHandler
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:725)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanPreProcessingException: Unerwarteter Fehler beim Verarbeiten von verwaltetem Bean indexHandler
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.preProcessBean(BeanManager.java:376)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:240)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:200)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:55)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:156)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:184)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:92)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:126)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:175)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:202)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:73)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:170)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:157)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:736)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1849)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:479)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:468)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:540)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1153)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1644)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:468)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:170)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:199)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:708)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanPreProcessingException: Unerwarteter Fehler beim Verarbeiten der verwalteten Eigenschaft '
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.bake(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.preProcessBean(BeanManager.java:331)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.getPropertyDescriptor(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:367)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.bakeListProperty(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:219)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.bake(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:81)
    ... 82 more
```

It seems like the problem is the class name of the bean in the faces-config.xml. The project got imported from an existing maven project with the package name: de.hsb.app.myfirst

so i tried: 
de.hsb.app.myfirst.MBindex
myfirst.MBindex
MBindex

Eclipse structure
[image]

Comment: Don't you have to give the managed property a name etc?

Comment: Two upvotes in 50 minutes?

Comment: And stacktraces inline in the question please. And you can debug, set breakpoints and check what is null

Comment: why do you think there is an invalid class name? Don't see anything about that in the stacktrace

Comment: But there is a `NullPointerException`. Do read the stack trace correctly.

Comment: @BalusC: But the source of Mojarra is open and setting a breakpoint is always possible. In combination with the 'red flag' on the faces-config that should give a good indication of what might be wrong (using the xsd might be as well).